# Opening a file (eg the second path) found by `locate` with `vim`

Tags: command-line, vim, locate

When I type something like `locate myfile.txt`, i get:

```
/opt/mydir/myfile1.txt.temp
/opt/mydir/myfile1.txt.temp2
/opt/mydir/myfile1.txt
/opt/mydir/myfile1.txt.temp4
```

I'd like to `vim` into the `N`-th result path. How can I do this without manually writing the path?

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
vim "$(sed -n "2 {p;q}" <(locate myfile.txt))"
```

Here i am opening the second newline separated result found by `locate myfile.txt` with `vim`.

Make it a function, and put in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
lovim () { vim "$(sed -n ""$2" {p;q}" <(locate "$1"))" ;}
```

The function takes first argument as the filename to search, and second argument as the number of resultant line (file) you want to open with `vim`.

**More robust**, tackling filenames with newlines in their names:

```
lovim () { vim "$(sed -nz ""$2" {p;q}" <(locate -0 "$1"))" ;}
```

**Example:**

```
lovim myfile.txt 3
```

will open the 3rd file from the result of `locate myfile.txt`.

**Expansion scope:**

- Adding some sanity checks on input and output (if the desired number of lines (file) present, before feeding to `vim`)